# How to create android studio library with fabric sdk?

Tags: java, android

I have integrated Twitter and all is done well.
But now I need to create a reusable component.

I.e.: a library using the fabric sdk in android studio.

We can get the fabric plugin from the Twitter developer site.
By using that I'm able to add sdk to an Android Studio project, but not to a library.

How to add this sdk to an Android Studio library project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define the classpath in your project's `build.gradle` as usual.

**Add the dependencies to your library module** as you would suspect.

**Apply the `io.fabric` plugin in your app module.** No way around this, that's by design. Fabric needs application ID, libraries don't have one.

EDIT: Due to manifest merging you are able to specify the API key meta-data (e.g. for Crashlytics) in your library's manifest.

EDIT 2: Looks like there's a page for it. <s>http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/456258-library-subproject-in-gradle</s>
https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#set-up-a-library-subproject

Answer (score 1):

For creating reusable component with fabric sdk.update your gradle to something like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Do rebuild your project after updating gradle file.you wil get the skd access now.